# Emacs 24.3 errors when toggling maximization

Tags: emacs

I have the following snippet in my `.emacs` file to toggle on and off the maximization of a given Emacs window (i.e. pane) within a frame. This code worked great until the introduction of Emacs 24.3

```
(defun toggle-maximize-buffer () "Maximize buffer"
  (interactive)
  (if (= 1 (length (window-list)))
    (jump-to-register '_)
    (progn
      (set-register '_ (list (current-window-configuration)))
      (delete-other-windows))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-F") 'toggle-maximize-buffer)
```

When I now maximize a pane with `M-F`, it works well, but when I unmaximize it (again with `M-F`) I get the error:

```
Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil
```

I can't tell why this happens. Did anything substantial change in this new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what might have changed. However you should not be using registers for programming. The following code uses a variable instead and does not have the error:

```
(defun toggle-maximize-buffer () "Maximize buffer"
  (interactive)
  (if (= 1 (length (window-list)))
    (set-window-configuration my-saved-window-configuration)
    (progn
      (setq my-saved-window-configuration (current-window-configuration))
      (delete-other-windows))))
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I believe I got my original code from EmacsWiki or another thread in StackOverflow. This is great to know!